# How to check if resource exists prior to sending a request?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check whether the resource at a given endpoint exists before sending out a GET request?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539269/http-head-vs-get-performance)

Comment: You can send a Head request? There's no way for you to know unless you make contact with the server

Comment: How would I 'send a Head request'? Will that return a boolean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax you send the request then check the response status

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HEAD, but whether or not it's actually worth it depends on the resource you're requesting, really.

Or create a new request that checks for resource existence and use the results of that to determine if you should bother fetching the resource.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get at: to determine whether I am going to fetch it in the future or not.

Comment: @NikitaTomkevich *Going* to, or *can*? In any case, if it's a small resource, I'd just grab it. If it isn't, or you're optimizing for mobile or something, then a HEAD request is probably what you want. As to what it returns, it depends on what you're calling. For example, IIRC Rails used to handle a HEAD request as a GET so you had to check manually and use a `head` response.

Comment: I'm not sure why this wasn't immediately obvious to me, but after I banged my head against my keyboard for a while, pun intended, I finally figured out that HEAD was just another REST method like GET or POST. This insight might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check if a resource is available is to try to fetch it and see if it exists.

You could cache a list and at least you wouldnt need to try twice but there is no way around it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript supports Try/Catch statements, we can give more detailed answers if specifically referenced functions or libraries are mentioned in the question.

see also:

- [catch-http-client-request-exceptions-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328540/how-to-catch-http-client-request-exceptions-in-node-js)
- [wrap-every-express-js-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690756/how-can-i-wrap-every-express-js-request-in-a-domain-or-trycatch)